# Spring Batch using eclipse or STS

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring Batch. I want to understand by making some simple Hello World or by reading a CSV file. On internet I saw many examples but everyone is explaining the code but nobody is talking about project structure or how to create project in eclipse or STS. Please provide me links which can explain the process very simple or share the articles for it.

Comment: Start like a simple Java project, you will learn a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a guide providing exactly what you are looking for (how to structure the project, Maven/Gradle config, code, etc) on the spring.io web site:

http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

It's generally a good idea to follow the tutorials on spring.io before following tutorials from anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

You can **download and import** a simple Spring Batch project **directly from STS**:

1. Click: File -> New -> Spring Project
2. In the "New Spring Project" Window, under "Templates", expand the "Batch" folder.
3. Click on "Simple Spring Batch Project", provide aproject name and click the "Next" button.

That's it. The project has what I would call a simple spring and spring-batch standard setup. You can easily extend it by adding an ORM-framework or whatever you like ...