# Why two thread accessing same data while reading from database?

Tags: multithreading, spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

Here the code i tried but multiple thread are accessing same data in database ....

MY XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans 
     xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


<bean id="JobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>


<batch:job id="firstjob">
       <batch:step id="masterStep">
            <batch:partition step="step1" partitioner="rangePartitioner">
                        <batch:handler grid-size="1" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
            </batch:partition>
       </batch:step>
</batch:job>



<batch:step id="step1"  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <batch:tasklet >
            <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="ItemWriter" commit-interval="1" >
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>


<bean id="rangePartitioner" class="com.spring.itemreader.Partioner" />

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />


<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseType" value="mysql" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>


<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
            <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql" />
            <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>




<bean id="itemReader"  class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />             
                <property name="sql" value="select id  from reader where id  &gt;= ? and id &lt;= ? " />
                <property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="readersetter"/>
                <property name="rowMapper" ref="rowmapprer"/>
</bean>         

<bean id="rowmapprer" class="com.spring.itemreader.rowmapprer">
      <property name="data" ref="data"/>
</bean>

<bean id="data" class="com.spring.itemreader.data" />

<bean id="ItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
        <property name="assertUpdates" value="false" />
        <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
                <bean class="com.spring.itemwriter.setter" />
        </property>
        <property name="sql"  value="INSERT INTO writer VALUES(?)" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>


<bean id="readersetter" class="com.spring.itemreader.readersetter" scope="step">
            <property name="fid" value="#{stepExecutionContext[fromId]}"/>
            <property name="tid" value="#{stepExecutionContext[toId]}"/>
</bean>


</beans>
```

**and my partitioner class is:**

```
 public class Partioner implements Partitioner{

    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {

//map for storing:

    Map<String, ExecutionContext> result 
                       = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();

        int range = 100;
        int fromId = 1;
        int toId = range;
        ExecutionContext value=null;

 using for loop i am giving range id and ExecutionContext

        for (int i = 1; i <= gridSize; i++) {
         value = new ExecutionContext();

            System.out.println("\nStarting : Thread" + i);
            System.out.println("fromId : " + fromId);
            System.out.println("toId : " + toId);

            value.putInt("fromId", fromId);
            value.putInt("toId", toId);

            // give each thread a name, thread 1,2,3
            value.putString("name", "Thread" + i);

            result.put("partition" + i, value);

            fromId = toId + 1;
            toId += range;


        }

        return result;
    }
```

and my reader setter 
public class readersetter implements PreparedStatementSetter {

```
private int fid;
private int tid;
public int getFid() {
    return fid;
}
public void setFid(int fid) {
    this.fid = fid;
}
public int getTid() {
    return tid;
}
public void setTid(int tid) {
    this.tid = tid;
}
@Override
public void setValues(PreparedStatement se) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    se.setInt(1,fid);
    se.setInt(2,tid);


}
```

but above working fine for grid size 1,its not working when i increase size ,please help with this issue...

When I increase my grid size this is what  am facing

Starting : Thread1
start : 1
end : 110

Starting : Thread2
start : 111
end : 220

Starting : Thread3
start : 221
end : 330

Starting : Thread4
start : 331
end : 440

Starting : Thread5
start : 441
end : 550

**Error** PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO writer VALUES(?)]; Duplicate entry '331' for key 'PRIMARY'; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '331' for key 'PRIMARY'

like that everytime am getting same error,other thread range are changed while accessing DB....

**Sysout of Rowmapper and WriterSetter**
Starting : Thread1
fromId : 1
toId : 
220

Starting : Thread2
fromId : 221
toId : 
440

row mapper221

row mapper1

writer1

writer1

row mapper2

writer2

row mapper3

Comment: did you look at SB sample projects? it should contains an example about partition

Comment: @ Luca Basso Ricc ,if you have any reference please give

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447498/sample-spring-batch-project-download

Comment: Have you looked in the db to confirm that each Step ExecutionContext has a unique range of ids?

Comment: @Michael Minella , Thanks for reply . In My DB range is different ,like when i put sysout for partition its showing like 1 to 250 but in DB it writing data from 2 to 251 (its skiping my partition range) ,i don't how this range is changing

Comment: Can you add the code for your readersetter bean?

Comment: @Michael Minella  ,Added code for readersetter bean and added my whole Xml content....

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong here.  My only other suggestion would be to put a `System.out` in the reader setter to verify that the values are begin passed to the partitions correctly (your current `System.out`'s just verify that the partitions are being created correctly).

Comment: @Michael Minella ,checked in reader setter as well .it showing same range Value.But I put sysout in writersetter it returning multiple values in setter(i.e its repeating value 1 two times ) because of that i getting duplicate vales while inserting

Comment: @Michael Minella ,,I just added Sysout for My Rowmapper and Writer Setter ,same Values writing twice(added result above).Thank You......:) –

Comment: I have the exact same problem using local partitioning and JpaItemWriter. The partition ranges are correct with unique IDs but the writers sooner or later throw unique-constraint exception. Only when grid-size=1 it works.

Comment: Update for my case: finally it was as issue with my Processor. The reader was processing correctly one item at a item but my processor was performing a jpql query at some other table in order to produce items for the writer. In that jpql query I had neglected the "distinct" keyword. So I was getting duplicate root entities. This was the real root cause of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your partitioning logic.Change your for loop with the following.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= gridSize; i++) {

            toId = fromId + blocksize;
            ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();


            if (fromId > totalRecords) {
                break;
            }

            if (toId > totalRecords) {
                toId = totalRecords;
                System.out.println("\nStarting : Thread" + i);
                System.out.println("fromId : " + fromId);
                System.out.println("toId : " + toId);

                value.putDouble("fromId", fromId);
                value.putDouble("toId", toId);
                // give each thread a name, thread 1,2,3
                value.putString("name", "Thread" + i);

                result.put("partition" + i, value);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("\nStarting : Thread" + i);
                System.out.println("fromId : " + fromId);
                System.out.println("toId : " + toId);

                value.putDouble("fromId", fromId);
                value.putDouble("toId", toId);


                value.putString("name", "Thread" + i);

                result.put("partition" + i, value);

                fromId = toId + 1;
            }

        }
```

Comment: @ Dangling Piyush ,thanks for reply.but my issue is sometimes its working fine (1 out 10) when i increase grid size . but mostly it end up falied . In your partitioner, code is fine In sysout it displaying correct partition but while accessing DB ,thread try to get same data and ended up failing .

Comment: @ Dangling Piyush ,And i synchronized reader as well .if you know any solution please help :)

Comment: Post code of your reader how your are accessing data fromId and toId attributes from ExecutionContext.